# Animate layer opacity causes sublayers to first get 100% opacity before fade occurs

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

I have this code for animating the opacity of a layer, that works exactly as intended except for one thing: Sublayers that have an alpha value lower than 100% get 100% opacity before the fade starts.

This means that the fade out looks unsmooth because a "blink" occurs on the sublayers that are semi-transparent.

Any ideas?

```
CABasicAnimation *fadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[fadeAnimation setDuration:1];
[fadeAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.layer.opacity]];
[fadeAnimation setToValue:@0];
[fadeAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[fadeAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[view.layer addAnimation:fadeAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
```

Comment: The code does what it should, it reads the opacity from the model of the layer. Avoid using `removeOnCompletion` unless you know what it does (i.e. know the difference between `modelLayer` and `presentationLayer`).

Comment: As I tried to tell in the question: This code works just as I want it to, except for that sublayers of the animated layers that have less opacity than the main layer first get the opacity of the main layer before animating to the new opacity. This causes a "blink" when a 40% layer suddenly becomes 100% because the main layer is 100%.